# Filter based on values contained in array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to filter dataset based on values that are contained in the array. So I want to only output the entries that have arrays which contain specific value.

I tried

```
 {
      "$in": [
         "$$t.Supplier Manager",
             [
               "Arnold Khan"
              ]
           ]
 }
```

However on this data I get empty output:

```
[
  {
    "level_1": "A",
    "cols": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ],
    "arno": "DC",
    "table": [
      {
        country: "NO",
        population: 400,
        color: "red"
      },
      {
        country: "AE",
        population: 100,
        color: "red"
      },
      {
        country: "OT",
        population: 200,
        color: "blue"
      },
      {
        country: "AU",
        population: 200,
        color: "red",
        alo: "n"
      },
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "level_1": "A",
    "cols": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ],
    "arno": "CD",
    "table": [
      {
        country: "NO",
        population: 200,
        color: "blue",
        "Supplier Manager": "['Arnold Khan']"
      },
      {
        country: "AE",
        population: 200,
        color: "red",
        "Supplier Manager": "[]"
      },
      {
        country: "OT",
        population: 200,
        color: "blue",
        "Supplier Manager": "['Adam Nor', 'Jim Brown']"
      },
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "level_1": "B",
    "cols": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ],
    "arno": "CD",
    "table": [
      {
        country: "AL",
        population: 400,
        color: "red",
        alo: "y"
      },
      {
        country: "AR",
        population: 100,
        color: "green",
        alo: "y"
      },
      {
        country: "YU",
        population: 200,
        color: "red",
        alo: "y"
      },
      {
        country: "AX",
        population: 200,
        color: "red",
        alo: "n"
      },
      
    ]
  }
]
```

However I should at least get this value out:

```
  {
    country: "NO",
    population: 200,
    color: "blue",
    "Supplier Manager": "['Arnold Khan']"
  },
```

Here is the playground with the data and attempted code, it is returning empty data but should return the value above.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/zgSJrZf7aPr

Comment: Did you want `"Supplier Manager": "['Arnold Khan']"` where the value, `"['Arnold Khan']"` is a string that _looks_ like an array?  I.e., `"['Arnold Khan']"` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You have passed the incorrect input in `$in` condition,

```
{ "$in": ["$$t.Supplier Manager", ["Arnold Khan"]] }
```

It should be matched with the present value like this,

```
{ "$in": ["$$t.Supplier Manager", ["['Arnold Khan']"]] }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RrkrPt6_P3Z)

---

Edit,

You can use `$regexMatch` operator to search that string instead of `$in` operator

```
{
  "$regexMatch": {
    "input": "$$t.Supplier Manager",
    "regex": "Arnold Khan",
    "options": "i"
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N_IPpO8vUuQ)

Comment: What about if I want to find those that have many different valuesin array? Like `Arnold Khan` and `Jim Brown`? ISnt your solution just matching the string?

Comment: As [@rickhg12hs mentioned in the comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143230/filter-based-on-values-contained-in-array-mongodb#comment130905643_74143230), your data looks incorrect. Presently the `"Supplier Manager"` field is _not_ an array. So this answer looks correct for what your current data is, but your current data looks incorrect

Comment: @AlexT it is hard to convert that string to an array in MongoDB, I have added another option that might help.